# Get this week equivalent from last year

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Working with SQL 2005 and I am trying to get this current weeks data equivalent from last year.

The week runs from Sunday to Friday. However as today is only Thursday I need the data from Sunday to Thursday from last year on this current date.

When I run the script again tomorrow it would need to be the data from a year ago for Sunday to - Friday.

Not really sure how to do this. Or even where to start, tried lots of things and lots of googling and not got anywhere, any suggestions?

Comment: If I rephrase your issue based on my understanding, will that help? You want to know how many days you are into the current week, then find the start date of that same week (based on weeknumber) in the previous year, then use the same number of days starting from there. Do note that only some years have a week 53

Comment: An immediate edge case which pops to mind is how you define a week?  Do you want the first complete week with a Sunday?

Comment: @HansKeﬆing I have a report that reports on how much money has been taken so far this week. Sunday to currentday (Thursday). I need to know what they took for the same period last year Sunday - Thursday. However when I re-run the rpeort tomorrow I need to know Sunday - Friday

Comment: And what would you do on 2018-02-29?

Comment: @GordonLinoff it is not required. This is a 6 month solution and next year is not a leap year.